# Generically select a textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, textarea

I am looking for a way to select a textarea from some element on the page via a jQuery selector but can't seem to figure it out.

Here is an example what I have tried:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ColdToast/ta8Pz/)

I would like to use the `:input[type='blah']` but `'textarea'` doesn't seem to be the correct syntax. Or possible create my own selector but Im not sure how to select just the textarea in the first place.

Comment: `<textarea>` elements are `<textarea>` elements.

Comment: Right... I guess was looking for a pseudo-selector for textarea... guess there isnt one per say

Comment: Why do you need a pseudo-selector for only `<textarea>` elements when you can just select using `textarea`, just like you select `div` or `li` elements?

Comment: No specific reason really. Just a curiosity thing. :)

Comment: I guess I was wondering because I saw that there is a :text selector and thought I'd be neat to have a :textArea ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<textarea>` is not an `<input type="textarea">`.

What's wrong with `$('textarea')`? ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/RQxnS/))

**Edit** It's unfortunate that, while `$(':input')` will confusingly include `textarea`s, there is no variant to select *just* `textarea`s through it. I see now why you were confused. As above, just look for `textarea` elements directly.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yea, I had wanted to limit changes to the original code, but now you mention it...

Comment: ':input' grabs (almost) all types of form elements, it includes 'textarea'. You are confusing with 'input'. So it's not unfortunate, -1 for that comment (will confuse readers)

Comment: @Edgar: How so? My comment _says_ that it includes `textarea`, but that there is no variant to select _only_ `textarea`s via `:input`. I have changed the wording very slightly; hopefully it'll be clearer now.